# How to view logical file with multiple Recordformats In AS/400?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have made a multiformat logical file in as400. When I run it, only one record format fields are displayed. Second record format fields are not seen. what is the procedure to see all record format fields?

Comment: I don't think you can do it in a query.  In WRKQRY, you can specify which format you want to see, but you may only choose 1.  SQL won't let your view it at all.  To flip through the multi-format records just to see what's there, try DFU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with RPG. Define the logical file in the F-specs, using one unique indicator for every record layout. Read the file and the indicators let you know which record layout is in the inputbuffer.

Also, you beter start reading the [RPG Programmer's guide](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/books/sc092507.pdf), and get a grip on the [RPG Reference guide](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/books/sc092508.pdf). You will **NEVER** understand this type of iSeries specific stuff by trying, guessing, or using Stack Overflow. Least said, it is quite different from other systems. So, you must be prepared for some steep learning.

BTW even for the iSeries, multiple format files are a little bit exotic. Therefore, don't create them for new applications.

Comment: +1 for different from other systems.  This is very true.  Just try to agree with others on what a FILE is...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tracy Probst.
It is possible through both WRKQRY and UPDDTA(i.e. STRDFU - option 5).
While using both the above commands, take F4-Prompt to select other than *FIRST member(which will be the default) of the physical file.

Note: RUNQRY will not allow other than *FIRST member, hence you will not be able to see any other member's data, No matter how many times you try.

Comment: If you prompt the RUNQRY command, you'll see there is a parameter for specifying the member, which doesn't have to be *FIRST.